# PHP: easy random picture code

Tags: php, image, random, photo

My code is random but its does not print out the picture just the text. When I add the IMAGE tag. Its go all wrong. Where do I go wrong?

```
$plaatje[] = 'afbeelding1.jpg';
$plaatje[] = 'afbeelding2.jpg';
$plaatje[] = 'afbeelding3.jpg';
$plaatje[] = 'afbeelding4.jpg';
$nummer2 = mt_rand(1,4);

echo "$plaatje[$nummer2]";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_rand()` -  *Picks one or more random entries out of an array*

```
echo $plaatje[array_rand($plaatje)];
```

With an image tag, something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo $plaatje[array_rand($plaatje)]; ?>" />
```

or

```
echo "<img src='".$plaatje[array_rand($plaatje)]."' />";
```

Here is the [documentation](https://www.php.net/array_rand)

Answer (score 1):

Although you should add the image tag to show where it goes wrong, your code already has a problem as array indices are 0-based.

So you would need:

```
$nummer2 = mt_rand(0,3);
```